# React Native - Fetch data from API with Authorization Bearer Token

Tags: react-native, api, bearer-token

I am trying to fetch data of user profile and I got this error

"Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0" in my Android Simulator

I checked with in my console.log and I manage to get my API properly so I think that is not the issue

This is my Home index.js (the file trying to fetch data)

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {getData} from '../../utils';

export default function Home() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');
  useEffect(() => {
    getData('token').then(res => {
      const res_token = res;
      console.log('token response: ', res_token);
      setToken(res_token);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://emaillead.aturtoko.id/api/v1/profile', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: token,
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        console.log('token auth: ' + token);
        setData(json);
        console.log(json);
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }, [token]);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Nama: {data.name}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

So I got the token from my login page. I tried to make 2 useEffect, one to get the token and the other to get the data from API. I also tried the only 1 useEffect before as well with the same result.

This is the code when I use only 1 useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    getData('token').then(res => {
      const res_token = res;
      console.log('token response: ', res_token);
      setToken(res_token);
    });
    fetch('https://emaillead.aturtoko.id/api/v1/profile', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: token,
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        console.log('token auth: ' + token);
        setData(json);
        console.log(json);
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }, [token]);
```

I don't know where is the problem with my code right now

Comment: You said you are using Bearer token so you need to use this ``Bearer ${token}``,